# Two knight tours on a 4x4 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess

Two knights are placed on opposite corners of a 4x4 grid. Can you move* each knight 7 times, such that each cell of the grid is visited exactly once by exactly one of the knights?

*Note that a knight moves 1 cell in one direction (horizontal or vertical) and two cells in an orthogonal direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible answer is

> ```
> . 2 . .
> . . 6 3
> 5 . 1 .
> 0 . 4 7
>
> 7 . 5 0
> 4 1 . .
> . 6 . 2
> . 3 . .
> ```

It doesn't look very symmetric at first glance, but if you look more closely,

> Both knights exit the corner (0-1), cycle through four cells on the sides (2-5), and then enter another corner (6-7).

<s>I think it's likely that there isn't any answer which does not follow this pattern.</s> I'm pretty sure this property holds for all answers, with the following reasoning:

Let's classify the cells into four categories.

```
A B C D
C D A B
B A D C
D C B A
```

And let's assume the two knights start at the two corner D's, as in my solution at the top.

Then we can observe some facts:

1. The two center D's must be the first moves of both knights. This is the only way for both to escape the corners. This settles the (0-1) part.
2. There are some restrictions on moving between different groups. A knight can't move from A to D directly, nor can it move from B to C directly (and vice versa).
3. For any knight, the only way to step on an A is to step on one of center A's first. Then it should move into one of the corner A's (otherwise there's no way to cover both corner A's). If a knight uses three cells, then it must use all four and stop at the second corner A. This means that the knight follows the path of D-D-B-B-A-A-A-A (or C's instead of B's), and then the other knight must go over two D's, two B's, and four C's, and the first two steps must be D. This is impossible by **2**. Therefore, both knights must occupy two A's each, finishing at the corners.
4. Now the two knights' paths are D-D-?-?-?-?-A-A. Since the remaining cells are B's and C's, and by **2**, the two paths must be D-D-B-B-B-B-A-A and D-D-C-C-C-C-A-A respectively.

Assuming the initial positions are fixed at the corner D's, we have two choices with center D's, two choices with assigning B/C, and two choices with corner A's. So we can find 8 different solutions.

Comment: Very well done and very fast! Can you find any other solutions?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Please see my edit.

Comment: That's it you got it!